# nginx returns Internal Server Error when uploading large files (several GB)

Tags: nginx, artifactory

I have an Artifactory behind nginx and uploading files larger than 4 GB fails. I am fairly certain that this is nginx's fault, because if the file is uploaded from/to localhost, no problem occurs.

nginx is set up to have `client_max_body_size` and `client_body_timeout` large enough for this not to be an issue.

Still, when uploading a large file (>4 GB) via curl, after about half a minute it fails. The only error message I get is `HTTP 500 Internal Server Error`, nothing is written to the nginx's error logs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem in my case was insufficient disk space mounted on root. I have a huge disk mounted on `/home`, but only had about 4 GB left on `/`. I assume that nginx was saving incoming request bodies there and after it had filled up, the request was shut down.

The way I fixed it was to add those lines to the `nginx.conf` file (not all of them are necessarily required):

```
http {
    (...)
    client_max_body_size 100G;
    client_body_timeout 300s;

    client_body_in_file_only clean;
    client_body_buffer_size 16K;
    client_body_temp_path /home/nginx/client_body_temp;
}
```

The last line is the important part - there I tell nginx to fiddle with its files in the `/home` space.

Comment: Just FYI, sometimes `/tmp` is a good directory if you don't have another set up for this