# Docker Windows Local Registry: received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: docker, containers, docker-registry, docker-for-windows

I am attempting to push an image of a windows container to a "local" repository on a Windows VM, which has it's own IP address.

So when I create the registry on my VM, I can view the repository list on my local machine by going to the ipaddress:5000 just fine.

However, when I try to push an image to the registry it shows the layers to be pushed but at the bottom it says received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error.

This isn't a problem when I switch to Linux containers. I can push and pull from the registry no problem.

Comment: Same error on linux -> aws ECR Docker Registry : `Handler for POST /v1.41/images/create returned error: received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error` and `Not continuing with pull after error: error pulling image configuration: received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error`

Answer (score 6):

You need to allow non distributable artifacts by setting the "`allow-nondistributable-artifacts`" option in the daemon configuration JSON file.

**For Linux:** Create or update the docker daemon JSON file with the above option at `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

**For Windows:**

1. Right click on **Docker** icon in the system tray and select **settings**
2. Select the **Daemon** tab
3. Enable **Advanced** option (if disabled)
4. Add the option **`allow-nondistributable-artifacts`** into the JSON Like:

   ```
   {
       "registry-mirrors": [],
       "insecure-registries": [],
       "debug": true,
       "experimental": true,
       "allow-nondistributable-artifacts": [
           "localhost:5000"
       ]
   }
   ```
5. Replace `localhost` with the name of your own server name.
6. Alternatively, the `daemon.json` file is located under `C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json`

**Note**: If you have any other settings, ONLY `allow-nondistributable-artifacts` is important/required.

Answer (score 5):

To me the problem was that our registry was full. I emptied it and it worked.

Comment: This was it for me too! Running `docker image prune -a` removed the unused and dangling images. That was enough for me to push my new image.

Answer (score 2):

It could be because of an error on the remote server(or local server) where you want to push your image. In my case it was a disk space issue which was thrown as a 500 Server Error. The issue needs to be checked on the server where the image is being pushed.

All of your images were pushed except a few ones because all the others were already pushed and the ones which were new failed.

Answer (score 2):

In my case i just waited for a while and tried again. 500 errors went away.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32009900)

Answer (score 2):

If you have nginx in front of the registry, nginx has an issue that PATCH of a large file might throw 500 Internal server error. It's caused by running out of disk space on root partition.

See here how to fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38873781/2032777

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Using Nexus as local registry) When I've checked the logs of nexus I noticed that the issue due to lack of storage.