# Docker push to local registry fails with error 500

Tags: windows, docker, docker-registry

I am attempting to push an image to a local docker registry. I have already added the address ofthe registry into the `insecure-registry` of the daemon.json file.

The `push` command end with the Following error: `received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error`.

Another similar question here on SO has an answer proposing to add `allow-nondistributable-artifacts` key to the daemon.json.
[Docker Windows Local Registry: received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56636181/docker-windows-local-registry-received-unexpected-http-status-500-internal-ser)

For me, adding `allow-nondistributable-artifacts` into the daemon.json allowed me to get a different output from the docker push process but it gave the same error in the end. After the line was added and restarting the docker daemon, the console now prints

```
a7ba3db29ebb: Retrying in 5 seconds
43b114b03480: Retrying in 5 seconds
a7ba3db29ebb: Retrying in 4 seconds
43b114b03480: Retrying in 4 seconds
a7ba3db29ebb: Retrying in 3 seconds
43b114b03480: Retrying in 3 seconds
a7ba3db29ebb: Retrying in 2 seconds
43b114b03480: Retrying in 2 seconds
43b114b03480: Retrying in 1 second
a7ba3db29ebb: Retrying in 1 second
43b114b03480: Retrying in 10 seconds
a7ba3db29ebb: Retrying in 10 seconds
...
```

and then fails with the error `received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error`.

How can I get past this error and push my image in the registry? Is there a way to have a more verbose error?

Comment: What do the logs on the registry show?